# Inverse of $1-ba$ when $a,b$ are the elements of unital algebra $A$

Tags: spectral-theory, spectral-sequences

I know if $a,b$ are elements of a unitral algebra $A$, then $1-ab$ is invertible if and only if $1-ba$ is invertible. And it follows from the observation that if $1-ab$ has inverse $c$ then $1-ba$ has inverse $1+bca$. But I can't prove it.

Comment: I don't know much about unitral algebras, but problems that look like this are usually solved by writing down $(1-ba)(1+bca)$ and simplifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we're given that $(1-ab)c=1$. That is, $c-abc=1$. Then:
\begin{align}
(1-ba)(1+bca)&=1+bca-ba-babca\\
&=1-ba+b(c-abc)a\\
&=1-ba+b(1)a\\
&=1-ba+ba\\
&=1
\end{align}